# How to add jdk in a.jar file and run it

Tags: java, jar

I have made a runnable .jar file. I want to run it on a PC which does not have jdk instilled, Can I add jdk in .jar file itself and run it ?

Comment: You only need a JRE to execute the JAR, not the full JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that your have installed your Java in the following path:

1 - copy this jre folder
**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre**

now all you need is to create a .bat text file with the following content:

```
@echo off
jre\bin\java -jar your_filename.jar
```

2 - name it as **run.bat**

that's all you need.

To wrap up things, the directory structure should be:

```
|---jre
   |---bin
   |---... // other files and folders
|---run.bat
|---your_filename.jar
```

click or create shortcut from run.bat and that's it.

If you are more interested in having a stand-alone executable file, then take a look at Launch4j (**google it :)** )

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the JDK for it to run, just the JRE (Java Runtime Environment).  You can download the JRE from [here](http://java.com/en/).

This is, unfortunately for you, something that will be needed to execute your code.